# How do i loop through each entry in a string delimited by a comma and include it as a separate input using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, arcpy

I have a string called listnumber

```
listnumbers
'1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0'
```

I have a function that returns each value of that string

```
def myfun(lists): 
   return ','.join([i for i in lists.split(',')])
```

When i type the function

```
myfun(listnumbers)
'1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0'
```

I have a loop script

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
for lyr in m.listLayers("OMAP_PCT_POP_ACS17"):
   if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
       lyr.definitionQuery="Value=" ""+myfun(listnumbers)+""
```

I end up getting

```
Value=1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0
```

What i would really like is for this to loop and give me

```
Value=1.0
Value=2.0
Value=3.0
```

and so on...... As separate entries. I feel i am very close i just need to make some changes.

Comment: Are you aware that your `myfun()` function does almost nothing?

Comment: Hint: You don't need to use `join`.

Comment: `myfun()` is splitting and joining by same delimiter. It neither added anything new nor changed anything  You just need `for x in listnumbers.split(','): lyr.definitionQuery = "Value=" + x`

Comment: The only thing the `myfun` function is doing it's adding is algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining the string back together, just leave it apart:

```py
def myfun(lists): 
   return [i for i in lists.split(',')]
```

Then, in your loop, you should loop through the values of the list returned by `myfun`:

```py
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
for lyr in m.listLayers("OMAP_PCT_POP_ACS17"):
   if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
       for value in myfun(listnumbers):
           lyr.definitionQuery = "Value=" + value
```

However, `str.split` already does what this improved `myfun` does, since it already returns a list. Thus, you can simplify even further and get rid of `myfun` entirely:

```py
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
for lyr in m.listLayers("OMAP_PCT_POP_ACS17"):
   if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
       for value in listnumbers.split(','):
           lyr.definitionQuery = "Value=" + value
```